# TeXstudio crashes after compilation due to "exception_access_violation"

Tags: texstudio

Please, help me in TeXstudio configuration,, the file is compiled normally then closed without showing the PDF. I think the problem in DVI viewer.

[image]

Please, check my configuration in attachment.
Thanks in advance

[image]

Comment: Can you reproduce it? Then you should file a bug report.

Comment: The dvips error sounds as if your eps-files are faulty. Try to compile from the command line to check if dvips complains there too.